# How to only grab a limited quantity in soup.find_all?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a certain website I'm trying to scrape on a frequent basis. I'm grabbing all the content I'd like, however, there's too many items in the soup.find_all (even after trying to specify with 'span' and class_=).

```
a = soup.find_all('span', class_=re.compile("headline")
```

where len(a) = 500. How can I program the logic such that I can only grab the first 10 headlines as opposed to 500? Looks like grabbing all 500 is causing my program to lag, which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the limit parameter as per Beautiful Soup DOcs

```
soup.find_all('title', limit=1)
# [<title>The Dormouse's story</title>]
```

Comment: So simple and elegant, thank you! Will accept your answer after the time restriction